# Nexus sonatype: Incomplete repository when adding a proxy repository

Tags: maven-2, nexus

We've installed the Nexus Sonatype open-source software, version 1.8.0.1 .
When we log in as an administrator and try to add a remote repository (proxy repository), the repository gets added but is incomplete and missing artifacts.

When we click on "`Browse Index`", we only see one artifact branch "`de`" when there should be multiple ones.
However, if we paste the repo url in a browser (`http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/`), there is a lot more content and also a `.index` directory which, by our understanding, should download a remote index of everything available in this repository.

The only error we see in the log is the following:

```
Aborted walking on repository ID='liferay-repository' from path='/.index', 
cause: Item not found on path "/.index" in repository "liferay-repository"!
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, the proxy repository downloads and caches the artifacts that it is requested.  It would not attempt to download the entire contents of the remote repository that is configured.

Could you try downloading artifacts in this remote repository using the configured Nexus proxy and see if the artifacts are present in Nexus after the operation?

Comment: The problem ended up being that we had to use another url, the url given to us on the andromda website that we were trying to use was invalid.  It just seemed like it should have been valid.  Cheers!